# Don't render Google AdSsense ads

Tags: javascript, adsense

I wonder if there is way of not rendering google adsense ads on a site? For instance, on staging sites. I imagine this as assigning a JS setting value before any ad script is called. Is this something google has provided an option for?

Comment: maybe not include the add scripts at all would help?

Comment: @toskv is this sarcasm? obviously this is not an option since I am askng for another way.

Comment: no it's not, you did not mention you can't do it in your question. :) If you can know that you are in staging on the client side you could just use that info to conditionally initialize the add scripts. if(!staging) { // initialize }

Comment: getting the actual value for the staging could be done by the server or via the build scripts (it depends on your setup).

Comment: I would advise against doing that though, because it gives your users the ability to turn them off as well by editing the client side code. It's much better to not include the script file initializing the adds in the staging bundle. :)

Comment: thanks @toskv, but as I have stated above, this is not an option. The ads come from content, inserted randomly in the middle of page content. Fixing this is not an option either, I am looking for a quick and dirty way of disabling the ads.

Comment: Users still can disable ads with browser extensions like AdBlock etc. And anticipating questions if I can use same extension, I have tried it, but didn't find an option for disabling ads on a particular site.